# What is Int, Out type in Akka (Scala)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am researching about Akka Stream. When i read an example about Balance in Akka.

What is **In** and **Out** type in this example?

```
def balancer[In, Out](worker: Flow[In, Out, Any], workerCount: Int): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = {
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b ⇒
    val balancer = b.add(Balance[In](workerCount, waitForAllDownstreams = true))
    val merge = b.add(Merge[Out](workerCount))

    for (_ ← 1 to workerCount) {
      // for each worker, add an edge from the balancer to the worker, then wire
      // it to the merge element
      balancer ~> worker.async ~> merge
    }

    FlowShape(balancer.in, merge.out)
  })
}

val processedJobs: Source[Result, NotUsed] = myJobs.via(balancer(worker, 3))
```

Comment: They are InputType and OutputType for your Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the definition of `Flow`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html):

> **Flow**
>
> A processing stage which has exactly one input and output, which
>   connects its up- and downstreams by transforming the data elements
>   flowing through it.

Generally speaking, `In` and `Out` are [type parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html). Specifically, they are used to convey the *input type*, which is type you put into the stream, and the *output type* which is the type produced by the stream.